# Dual Coxeter Number for Superalgberas

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, lie-superalgebras

I am looking for a reference that gives the definition and has summarized the dual Coxeter number for superalgebras, especially for $\mathfrak{u}(m|n)$ (the Lie algebra of unitary supergroup $U(m|n)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual Coxeter number for basic Lie superalgebras is given in the table on page 16 of [Kostant’s cubic Dirac operator of Lie superalgebras](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25269566.pdf). Also, the generalization of the Freudenthal-de Vries strange formula holds for Lie superalgebras as well (equation (38) of the above reference).

Comment: What is the definition of "dual Coxeter element" here?   Meanwhile, here is a more detailed description of Kostant's own article: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1719734